# Running application as windows service

Tags: windows-services

I have an application that is running as window service and its running under a valid use account not under default system account ,now my worry is if in future use changes his password for that account will it effect this service??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The service will stop working as the user credentials don't match.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The password you enter in the service properties must be changed of the user changes his password, so it's a bad idea to run a service under a real live user account.

You can either set it to run on a system account, and grant that account the necessary resources for the service to function, or you can create a pseudo-system account - a user account that is restricted from everything else, except from the service resources.

Comment: Thansk SWeko for ur response but how to i provide all most all privalges to system account(default ) means how do i make sure user account thata m using and deault account have equal grant

Comment: Well that depends on the service. If you require access to some files, you should add privileges to that folder, etc... Make sure to test the scenarios running it with the intended user, because often everything works when using an admin user, and then suddenly stops when a restricted account (such as LocalService) is used

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the password is changed for the user account, you need to update the stored password as well.
And to make this answer more programming related, this MSDN article shows you how to do it programmatically: [Changing the Password on a Service's User Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)